# badge view in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift

i Want to create a badgeView which is inserted in the cells accesoryView. I know this have been asked quite a lot in the past, but those github subclasses, seem to be outdated and cant be ported into an swift project. What is the easiest way to do it in IOS in a swift project?

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Which 'those github subclasses' are you referring to?

Comment: https://github.com/tmdvs/TDBadgedCell

Comment: I think you will need to customize UITableViewCell. I am not sure how to do it with Swift, but you can find tons of tutorial on internet for Objective-C. Here is one, http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

Comment: @gamerChristian The library you mentioned is not really outdated. The latest commit is just 3 months ago. I downloaded it and had a look. The implementation file is about 400 lines. It would take only a few hours to port it to Swift. But if it's an overkill for what you're trying to do, you have 2 options. Either use the library as it is using the ObjC bridging header. Or simply create a custom `UITableViewCell`.

Answer (score 36):

The following code has been testing in iOS7 and iOS8 and works as follows:

1. If count > zero, it will display the count in white text with a red badge around it.
2. If count = zero, it will display a simple disclosure indicator.

[image]

```
    - (void)updateTableViewCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forCount:(NSUInteger)count
    {
        // Count > 0, show count
        if (count > 0) {

            // Create label
            CGFloat fontSize = 14;
            UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
            label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontSize];
            label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            label.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

            // Add count to label and size to fit
            label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @(count)];
            [label sizeToFit];

            // Adjust frame to be square for single digits or elliptical for numbers > 9
            CGRect frame = label.frame;
            frame.size.height += (int)(0.4*fontSize);
            frame.size.width = (count <= 9) ? frame.size.height : frame.size.width + (int)fontSize;
            label.frame = frame;

            // Set radius and clip to bounds
            label.layer.cornerRadius = frame.size.height/2.0;
            label.clipsToBounds = true;

            // Show label in accessory view and remove disclosure
            cell.accessoryView = label;
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }

        // Count = 0, show disclosure
        else {
            cell.accessoryView = nil;
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

In **Swift 4**

```
extension UITableViewCell {
  func update(count: Int) {
    // Count > 0, show count
    if count > 0 {

        // Create label
        let fontSize: CGFloat = 14
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize)
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.textColor = UIColor.white
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        // Add count to label and size to fit
        label.text = "\(NSNumber(value: count))"
        label.sizeToFit()

        // Adjust frame to be square for single digits or elliptical for numbers > 9
        var frame: CGRect = label.frame
        frame.size.height += CGFloat(Int(0.4 * fontSize))
        frame.size.width = (count <= 9) ? frame.size.height : frame.size.width + CGFloat(Int(fontSize))
        label.frame = frame

        // Set radius and clip to bounds
        label.layer.cornerRadius = frame.size.height / 2.0
        label.clipsToBounds = true

        // Show label in accessory view and remove disclosure
        self.accessoryView = label
        self.accessoryType = .none
    } else {
        self.accessoryView = nil
        self.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

i used this code in the cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
    var accesoryBadge = UILabel()
    var string = "2"
    accesoryBadge.text = string
    accesoryBadge.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    accesoryBadge.font = UIFont(name: "Lato-Regular", size: 16)
    accesoryBadge.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    accesoryBadge.layer.cornerRadius = 4
    accesoryBadge.clipsToBounds = true

    accesoryBadge.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, WidthForView(string, font: UIFont(name: "Lato-Light", size: 16), height: 20)+20, 20)
    cell.accessoryView = accesoryBadge
```

Comment: This is pretty cook. I´ve tried to implement this in a Swift 2.0 project. But there is `WidthForView` not available. Can you provide a solution to calculate the width of the string

Comment: func widthForView(_ text:String, font:UIFont, height:CGFloat) -> CGFloat{
        let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: height))
        label.numberOfLines = 1
        label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
        label.font = font
        label.text = text
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.sizeToFit()
        return label.frame.width
    }